# What's the point of using 'Any' in Swift? When to use 'Any' and when to use 'AnyObject'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

[In Swift documentation, it says the following](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-XID_448):

> Swift provides two special type aliases for working with non-specific types:
>
> AnyObject can represent an instance of any class type.
> Any can represent an instance of any type at all, apart from function types.
> NOTE
>
> Use Any and AnyObject only when you explicitly need the behavior and capabilities they provide. It is always better to be specific about the types you expect to work with in your code.

If I understand it correctly, `AnyObject` should be used when it is compatible with class types, which means it cannot represent Swift's built-in `String`, `Int`, `Dictionary`, `Array`, etc... since those are all represented as structure, not class, in Swift.

However, when I write the following code, it can be compiled without any errors:

```
var myInt: Int = 10
var myStr: String = "st"
var myDict:Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = ["k1": "1", "k2": 2, "k3": true]
var myArr:Array<AnyObject> = []
myArr.append(myInt)
myArr.append(myStr)
myArr.append(myDict)
println(myArr)
```

Because I define `myArr` as `AnyObject[]`, it should be able to contain only class types, while `myInt`, `myStr`, and `myDict` are all compatible to `Any`, not `AnyObject`, and `Any` is not compatible with `AnyObject.

However, I think the reason it can be compiled is because `myInt` is convertible to Objective-C's `NSInteger` internally, which is a subtype of `AnyObject`. Same is true of `String`/`NSString` and `Dictionary`/`NSDictionary`. Is my guess correct? Then, here's my question:

- Even if you can define Swift's Array as `AnyObject` and still store Swift's structure like `Int` or `String`, what's the point of using `Any`? Is there any situation that you have to define an Array as `Any`? How about the `Dictionary`'s value type?
- How should I decide when to use `Any` and when to use `AnyObject`, especially if I deal with an type which can be convertible to Objective-C's Object, like `String`, `Int`, `Dictionary`, etc?

I think the most methods in Cocoa and Cocoa Touch return `AnyObject!`, not `Any!`. So I wonder what is the best case to use `Any` in Swift's Array and Dictionary's value type.

Comment: Looks like this changed in seed 2. I guess even they are not sure what they are doing.

Comment: I use Xcode 6 Beta 2. I also add `import Foundation`, but without it the code is compiled.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use Any[] to store custom structs.

Answer (score 1):

> However, when I write the following code, it can be compiled without
>   any errors:

Not if you don't have `import Foundation`. Without importing Foundation, there are lots of errors. It only compiles for you due to the bridging that Foundation has for numeric types to `NSNumber`, `String` to `NSString`, etc.